# Split a data.frame column into others columns

Tags: r, dataframe, split, multiple-columns

I have a big `data.frame` with some columns, but my 9th column is made of data separated by semicolon :

```
    gtf$V9
1                 gene_id CUFF.1; transcript_id CUFF.1.1; FPKM 7.0762407256; frac 1.000000; conf_lo 4.347062; conf_hi 9.805420; cov 25.616962;
2  gene_id CUFF.1; transcript_id CUFF.1.1; exon_number 1; FPKM 7.0762407256; frac 1.000000; conf_lo 4.347062; conf_hi 9.805420; cov 25.616962;
3  gene_id CUFF.1; transcript_id CUFF.1.1; exon_number 2; FPKM 7.0762407256; frac 1.000000; conf_lo 4.347062; conf_hi 9.805420; cov 25.616962;
4  gene_id CUFF.1; transcript_id CUFF.1.1; exon_number 3; FPKM 7.0762407256; frac 1.000000; conf_lo 4.347062; conf_hi 9.805420; cov 25.616962;
```

So I would like to cut this column into others columns and `merge` this later with the other part of the `data.frame` (the others columns before the 9th column).

I've tried some code without results :

```
head(gtf$V9, sep = ";",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

or

```
new_df <- matrix(gtf$V9, ncol=7, byrow=TRUE) # sep = ";"
```

The same thing with `as.data.frame`, `data.frame` or `as.matrix`

I have also tried to `write.csv` and import this with includ a `sep=";"`, but the `data.frame` is too bigger and my computer is lagging..

Any advice?

Comment: Eventually `read.table(text=gt$V9, sep=';')` ... and then `cbind()`

Comment: You are reading sequence variant data. Take a look at the refGenome package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/refGenome/vignettes/refGenome.pdf

Comment: You have to provide more info about how you want your ideal output to be. When you split `V9` by `;` do you get the values of your columns? Are the columns names included in `V9` as well? I'll take a guess and post an answer assuming the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use the `splitstackshape`-package (which also loads `data.table`). Using:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(cSplit(df, 'V9', sep = ';', direction = 'long'),
       'V9', sep = ' ')[, dcast(.SD, cumsum(V9_1 == 'gene_id') ~ V9_1)]
```

gives:

> ```
>    V9_1  conf_hi  conf_lo       cov exon_number         FPKM     frac gene_id transcript_id
> 1:    1 9.805420 4.347062 25.616962          NA 7.0762407256 1.000000  CUFF.1      CUFF.1.1
> 2:    2 9.805420 4.347062 25.616962           1 7.0762407256 1.000000  CUFF.1      CUFF.1.1
> 3:    3 9.805420 4.347062 25.616962           2 7.0762407256 1.000000  CUFF.1      CUFF.1.1
> 4:    4 9.805420 4.347062 25.616962           3 7.0762407256 1.000000  CUFF.1      CUFF.1.1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

you could do `strsplit()` within a `sapply()`

If you know how many objects can be in V9 than you can do a for loop over it

```
for (i in 1:number_of_max_objects_in_V9) {
 gtf[ncol(gtf)+1] = sapply(1:nrow(gtf), function(x) strsplit(gtf$V9[x],',')[[1]][i])
}
```

if you don't know how many objects can V9 have, then just run a `str_count` on `,` in gtf$V9 like this:

```
library(stringr)
number_of_max_objects_in_V9 <- max(sapply(1:nrow(gtf), function(x) str_count(gtf$V9,',')))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# example dataset (only variable of interest included)
df = data.frame(V9=c("gene_id CUFF.1; transcript_id CUFF.1.1; FPKM 7.0762407256; frac 1.000000; conf_lo 4.347062; conf_hi 9.805420; cov 25.616962;",
                "gene_id CUFF.1; transcript_id CUFF.1.1; exon_number 1; FPKM 7.0762407256; frac 1.000000; conf_lo 4.347062; conf_hi 9.805420; cov 25.616962;",
                "gene_id CUFF.1; transcript_id CUFF.1.1; exon_number 2; FPKM 7.0762407256; frac 1.000000; conf_lo 4.347062; conf_hi 9.805420; cov 25.616962;",
                "gene_id CUFF.1; transcript_id CUFF.1.1; exon_number 3; FPKM 7.0762407256; frac 1.000000; conf_lo 4.347062; conf_hi 9.805420; cov 25.616962;"),
                stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%                  # flag row ids (will need those to reshape data later)                
  separate_rows(V9, sep="; ") %>%                # split strings and create new rows
  separate(V9, c("name","value"), sep=" ") %>%   # separate column name from value
  mutate(value = gsub(";","",value)) %>%         # remove ; when necessary
  spread(name, value)                            # reshape data

#   id  conf_hi  conf_lo       cov exon_number         FPKM     frac gene_id transcript_id
# 1  1 9.805420 4.347062 25.616962        <NA> 7.0762407256 1.000000  CUFF.1      CUFF.1.1
# 2  2 9.805420 4.347062 25.616962           1 7.0762407256 1.000000  CUFF.1      CUFF.1.1
# 3  3 9.805420 4.347062 25.616962           2 7.0762407256 1.000000  CUFF.1      CUFF.1.1
# 4  4 9.805420 4.347062 25.616962           3 7.0762407256 1.000000  CUFF.1      CUFF.1.1
```

You can join this dataset back to your initial dataset using the row ids (`id`). You need to create an `id` in your original dataset as well.